# Does AngularJS 1.5 support Opera mini?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opera, opera-mini

I'm developing a mobile site using AngularJS (v 1.5)  and it doesn't load in Opera mini. So I started searching and found one article about how Opera mini is a proxy based server and it stripes maximum JavaScript data.
But except that one article, I haven't seen it stated explicitly that Opera mini isn't supported, so I'm a bit confused.

I know Angular 2 is supposed to be released with the view of mobile-first architecture, but does Angular 1.x support opera mini?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think AngularJS has a version 1.8 yet. Version 1.5.0 (from 2016-02-05) is the latest in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: oops sorry! typing mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Opera mini no longer supported by AngularJS. Check this:

https://mobiforge.com/news-comment/angularjs-to-opera-mini-youre-just-not-worth-it

**Edited:**
Quoting from [AngularJS FAQ](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/misc/faq) (latest stable v1.5):

> **What browsers does Angular work with?**
>
> We run our extensive test suite against the following browsers: the
>   latest versions of **Chrome**, **Firefox**, **Safari**, and **Safari
>   for iOs**, as well as **Internet Explorer versions 9-11**. See
>   Internet Explorer Compatibility for more details on supporting legacy
>   IE browsers.
>
> **If a browser is untested, it doesn't mean it won't work**; for example, older Android (2.3.x) is supported in the sense that we avoid
>   the dot notation for reserved words as property names, but we don't
>   actively test changes against it. You can also expect browsers to work
>   that share a large part of their codebase with a browser we test, such
>   as Opera > version 12 (uses the Blink engine), or the various Firefox
>   derivatives.

Comment: isn't it only for Angular 2.0?, I think questio concerns to the  Angular 1.8 version

Comment: I was talking about this article. I only could find this one source, and not any official documentation.

Comment: could you elaborate on this : "Opera > version 12"? does it include opera mini?

Comment: @SamiaRuponti: Up to and including version 12.x, the desktop version of Opera used the Presto layout engine, then switched to using Blink in 2013 from version 15 onwards (there were no official versions 13 & 14). Opera Mini still uses [Presto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_(layout_engine)).